# SkewX() math formula for full width (3 divs next to each other)

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, skew

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

.test {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.a {
  background: purple;
  left: 0;
}

.b {
  background: green;
  left: 33%;
}

.c {
  background: orange;
  left: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test a"></div>
  <div class="test b"></div>
  <div class="test c"></div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/7/

As you can see, because of the skew, you can still see the background of parent.
All 3 of the divs being equall, what would it be the formula so that it will fill 100% of the parent (so you can no longer see the black in the snippet code)? The parent dimensions can have different values.

I'm looking for something like `.a {left: calc(33% *0.4)}` or something like that?

Comment: maybe to calc width??

Comment: @לבנימלכה yes, but you still have to calc left too.

Comment: is it ok if the width of each part be bigger??

Comment: @לבנימלכה it would be really simple just to put them to 100% width and then overflow hidden on the parent, but it should work on very large screens, like street ones. so even 1000% width may be not enough to overcompansate the skew in some cases.

Comment: is it what you mean:http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/13/

Comment: @לבנימלכה think so, so what is the formula behind left: -19%; ?

Comment: you can use     `right: 68%;` instead

Comment: is it what you mean??

Comment: @לבנימלכה no, I was wondering why 19% and not 18%? how did you arrive at 19%? I'm guessing it is related to the degree of the skew right?

Comment: I only try and see what fit.... see here:http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/28/

Comment: @לבנימלכה hard coding the values this way it doesn't work, because if I change the dimensions of the parent then it will not fit the same,: http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/34/

Comment: NOW it fit to all sizes:http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/44/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Adjust the `transform-origin` to `bottom left` to make it easier and you will obtain the result shown in the image below.

Then you need to adjust both width and left properties by the amount `X` in order to cover the whole area. To calculate `X` you need to use the formula : `tan(deg) = X / height` (`X = height * tan(deg)`) where `deg` is the degree used for the skew and `height` is the height of the parent element. Since you have 3 elements this amount need to be split between them to always keep the same width.

[image]

I added some opacity so you can see that all the elements fit the width of the parent container:

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
}
.test {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  --X:calc(0.364 * 500px); /*tan(20deg) ~ 0.364*/
  transform-origin:bottom left;
  width:calc(calc(100%/3) + calc(var(--X)/3));
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0.8;
}
.a {
    background:purple;
    left:0;
}
.b {
  background:green;
  left:calc(calc(100%/3) + calc(var(--X)/3));

}
.c {
  background:orange;
  left:calc(calc(2*100%/3) + calc(2 * var(--X)/3));
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test a">

  </div>
  <div class="test b">

  </div>
  <div class="test c">

  </div>
</div>
```

Another way to obtain a similar effect with less of code is to use gradient:

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  margin:auto;
  position:relative;
  background:
  linear-gradient(70deg, purple 0,purple 33%, green 33%, green 66%,orange 66%,orange 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: what is `--X:calc(0.364 * 500px);` ? is it valid css?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga of course ;) these are CSS variables and they are useful in your case [update  my answer with better explanation.

Comment: thanks. so 500px here  --X:calc(0.364 * 500px) is the height and for a full page height I can just change it to 100vh. awesome. don't understand why it should be so complex.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga it's not complex it's Math :)

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I added another way to avoid math complexity if you want ;)

Comment: thanks, but I prefer the first one because I want to animate them individually on entry. :)

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga check this answer then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50996921/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-do-multi-step-animations/50999288#50999288 ;) you can also animate using gradient and without complex math

Answer (score 1):

Math says 44% width according to google, https://www.google.com/search?q=(33%25+%2B+sin(20 degrees)*33%25) but those value cause the center area to look much larger if that is applied to the left and right offsets.

Calc does not support mixed units so pre calculation looks like a requirement.

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  background:green;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.parent::before {
  content:'';
  background:purple;
  height:500px;
  width:44%; /* (33% + sin(20 degrees)*33%) = 44% */ 
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  position:absolute;
  left:-18%;
}
.parent::after {
  content:'';
  height:500px;
  width:44%;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  position:absolute;
  background:orange;
  right:-18%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">


</div>
```

Comment: prehaps when safari has support for clip-path: polygon the points can be calculated by unit value in variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try it, it has to fit all sizes:(see fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/85/)

```css
.parent {
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.test {
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.a {
    background:purple;
        right: 75%;
}
.b {
  background:green;
      right: 25%;

}
.c {
  background:orange;
      left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="test a">

  </div>
  <div class="test b">

  </div>
  <div class="test c">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but you can see that the purple is much smaller than the yellow: http://jsfiddle.net/jksqc1ux/70/ top left corner vs bottom right. All 3 divs have to be equal.